# R: How to output unique strings (text) in a data frame?

Tags: r, text, machine-learning

Please help.

I have a data frame of almost 40k data points (rows) and one of the columns contains a text. For instance,

```
ID  Text
 1  I love my mum I love my dad
 2  I live in AB I used to live in CD
 .  .
 .  .
```

I want it to output as follows:

```
ID  Text
 1  I love my mum dad
 2  I live in AB used to CD
 .  .
 .  .
```

I tried `unique()` and `make.unique()` but they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to remove any duplicated word from each sentence. If that's the case, you can try:

```
txt<-c("I love my mum I love my dad","I live in AB I used to live in CD")
vapply(strsplit(txt,"\\s+"),function(x) paste(unique(x),collapse=" "),"")
#[1] "I love my mum dad"       "I live in AB used to CD"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. May I know what is the last argument ("") for? Is it a function value, `FUN.VALUE` from `function(x)`? I thought it might not be the additional argument from `function(x)` since it only has one argument.